# UIScrollView Custom View rotation problem

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a ScrollView with a Custom View. Now i have the problem with the rotation, the view has after the rotation not the correct frame pos / size.

How can i call the CustomView after rotation for a reposition and resize the frame and content?!

```
- (void)setupPage
{
    NSUInteger nimages = 0;
    CGFloat cx = 0;
    for (; ; nimages++) {
        if (nimages == list.count) {
            break;
        }

        CustomStepView *stepView = [[CustomStepView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        stepView.tag = nimages;
        if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
        {

            stepView.frame = CGRectMake(cx, 0.0 , 768.0f, 926.0f);
            cx += 768.0;
        }
        else
        {
            stepView.frame = CGRectMake(cx, 0.0 , 1024.0f, 670.0f);
            cx += 1024.0;
        }

        [scrollView addSubview:stepView];
        [stepView release];

    }

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = nimages;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, You have a lot of subviews(Custom Views) in your ScrollView.

First of all never try to detect the orientation using UIDevice , it is not recommended by apple.
For handling rotations you have been provided with the function : "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation"

Inside this method, You can simple run a loop for detecting the subviews present inside your scrollview and then set the frame and size of each subview.

This might look something like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   if(interfaceOrientation ==  UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
   {
     for(UIView *asubview in scrollView.subviews)
     {
        asubview.frame = "NEW FRAME";    
     }
   }
   else
   {
       asubview.frame = "NEW FRAME";
   } 
}
```

Hope it helps you..although i know this has been asked long back :-) 
Cheers

Comment: You shouldn't change the frame inside the `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`. you make changes in the `-will...` or `-did...` methods.